# Bring multi-dimensional array down (unnest) one level

Tags: php

Althoug this works well enough, I am curious if anyone knows of a prettier way of doing this as this situation seems to come up quite often.

```
<?php
//Initialy,  data is nested up in $some_array[0] ...
$some_array = array(array('somevar' => "someValue", "someOtherVar" => "someOtherValue"));

print_r($some_array);
```

Array ( [0] => Array ( [somevar] => someValue [someOtherVar] => someOtherValue ) )

```
// Could the following line be achieved a more elegant fashion?
$some_array = $some_array[0];

print_r($some_array);

// Prints the intended result:
```

Array ( [somevar] => someValue [someOtherVar] => someOtherValue )

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this with a native function or in a more elegant fashion?

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with using `$some_array = $some_array[0];`? It seems fine to me...

Comment: Please define "more elegant". Also why is your data not more elegant in the first place if you strive for elegance that much? The native function is called [`reset`](http://php.net/reset) btw.

Comment: @hakre - More elegant was having a native function that returns first element of array, like current() seems to do. On re-thhinking on this a bit I would tend to favor my initial code example for readability, as one can see with half-a-glance and without thinking what is going on. 

Data is structured in this manner because it is the return value of a callback from a framework.

PS: reset needs to be used in conjunction with current(). In my case reset is somewhat redundant as I could call current() right after the function call.

Comment: @stefgosselin: You don't need to use `current` with `reset`, I added an answer for explicit clarification with not only some example code, but also some linked demonstration. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `current` (explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)), it basically points to the first element in the array and returns it.

To be absolutely sure you get the first element, you should reset your array, like so:

```
reset($arr)
$firstElement = current($arr)
```

Comment: [`reset`](http://php.net/reset) returns as well, so `$first = reset($array);` should be enough.

Comment: for a true (non-associative) array `reset` would suffice. But in the php.net documentation it mentions in the user comments that this does not work for associative arrays, which is why I added the `current` call.

Answer (score 2):

The native function you're looking for is called [`reset`](http://php.net/reset) ([Demo](http://codepad.org/P81AzleP)):

```
$some_array = reset($some_array);
```

For explicit clarification:  `current` is not necessary.

Comment: does not work, if array contains more, than 1 element on the upper level: reset([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) -> [1, 2, 3]

http://codepad.org/jqS2Tu23

Comment: @LajosMeszaros: That is one element: array. Sounds like you're looking for something different, like to flatten the array first: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/367456

Comment: The solution I ended up using is calling array_reduce on the input array with array_merge inside.

Comment: @LajosMeszaros: Or you may want to consider anything iterable moving empty elements out of the way, too: https://3v4l.org/1BK82